# How do I use regular expression to get a list of words in an Arabic string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have arabi text like these:

> احوال العدد، فی اللغة، العربیة

and I want to parse text(without `،` and remove space) from them, so I get

> 'احوال العدد'
>  'فی اللغة'
>  'العربیة'

Example:

```
var m = 'احوال العدد، فی اللغة، العربیة'
m.match(?);
```

Can someone help me with correct regex for that situation?

Comment: Please would you consider improving that title to something more descriptive of the problem?

Comment: I want a jQuery solution, for output `'احوال العدد'
'فی اللغة'
'العربیة'`. how is it?

Comment: @KateWintz: Sorry, I was in C# mode in my head :)  Deleted so I shouldn't scare away other answers now...

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - ok, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.split` if you want to split a string, not `.match`.

```
>>> var m = 'احوال العدد، فی اللغة، العربیة';
>>> res = m.split(/،\s*/)
["احوال العدد", "فی اللغة", "العربیة"]
>>> res[0]
"احوال العدد"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't use regex unless I have to.  Other options are usually faster for simple cases.

For example, if you just want to split on instances of a single character, try [`string.split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) instead of a regex:

```
var matches = m.split(" ");
```

#### You said:

> ... after `،` ...

Not sure what you mean by "after `،`".

#### Just remove it too?

If you just want to remove it too, `string.split` can still handle that:

```
var matches = m.split("، "); // Note that it seems to need LTR ordering...
```

The output you get looks like what you said you are expecting in your question:

> 'احوال العدد'
>   'فی اللغة'
>   'العربیة'

#### Return matches only after that character is found?

If you want to only return matches that are found after that character first occurs, I'd use [`string.indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [`string.substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

Here's some code that could achieve this (and demo - http://jsfiddle.net/U5Fz7/):

```
var m = 'احوال العدد، فی اللغة، العربیة'
var matchStartIndex = m.indexOf("،") + 1;
var matches = matchStartIndex > 0 && matchStartIndex < m.length
    ? m.substring(matchStartIndex).split(" ")
    : new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    document.write(matches[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

The extra code here is for error handling, in case `،` isn't found, or there are no characters after it.

The output you get is a little weird (the first string is empty), as the string ends up starting with a `" "`:

> ''
>   'فی'
>   'اللغة،'
>   'العربیة'

Comment: I think that Kate want a javascript solution, not a C# one

Comment: Changed my answer to javascript and undeleted it :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help you to erase ",":

```
var m = 'احوال العدد, فی اللغة, العربیة';
var strReplaceAll = m;
var intIndexOfMatch = strReplaceAll.indexOf( "," );

// Loop over the string value replacing out each matching
// substring.
while (intIndexOfMatch != -1){
// Relace out the current instance.
strReplaceAll = strReplaceAll.replace( ',',' ' )

// Get the index of any next matching substring.
intIndexOfMatch = strReplaceAll.indexOf( "," );
}
//print out the result


document.write(strReplaceAll);
```

the result could notice here: 
احوال العدد فی اللغة العربیة

Answer (score 0):

Without regex :

```
var str = 'احوال العدد، فی اللغة، العربیة';
var arr = str.split('،');
arr = $.map(arr, function(val, i) {
  return val.trim();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With RegExp:

```
x=m.match(/([\u0600-\u060B\u060D-\u06FF][\u0600-\u060B\u060D-\u06FF\s]+[\u0600-\u060B\u060D-\u06FF])/g);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/WpM4x/